# Using + and * in the aov() function

Tags: r, stat, anova

I am slightly confused as to what is the difference between + and *.

I want to do an ANOVA test on this data to see if the performance is affected by the method, where the tests a-d were repeated during 4 sessions.

I tried:

```
a = aov(perf~(method*test*sess))
summary(a)
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
method            2  894.0   447.0   5.794 0.00885 **
test              3  109.2    36.4   0.472 0.70466   
sess              1    9.2     9.2   0.119 0.73279   
method:test       6  425.5    70.9   0.919 0.49851   
method:sess       2  745.1   372.6   4.829 0.01727 * 
test:sess         3   98.2    32.7   0.425 0.73718   
method:test:sess  6  409.2    68.2   0.884 0.52162   
Residuals        24 1851.5    77.1                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I can see some significance in `method:sess` but I don't know if this accounts for the repeated readings during the 4 sessions? Also if I want to see if there is any significant difference between the sessions, would I need to put a "+" before sess when calculating aov?

The Data:

```
method  perf    test    sess
m1  39  a   1
m2  49  a   1
m3  40  a   1
m1  38  a   4
m2  32  a   4
m3  51  a   4
m1  39  a   2
m2  42  a   2
m3  45  a   2
m1  43  a   3
m2  54  a   3
m3  55  a   3
m1  26  b   1
m2  47  b   1
m3  55  b   1
m1  46  b   4
m2  48  b   4
m3  42  b   4
m1  37  b   2
m2  42  b   2
m3  42  b   2
m1  35  b   3
m2  30  b   3
m3  66  b   3
m1  40  c   1
m2  60  c   1
m3  37  c   1
m1  37  c   4
m2  32  c   4
m3  50  c   4
m1  50  c   2
m2  49  c   2
m3  55  c   2
m1  48  c   3
m2  29  c   3
m3  60  c   3
m1  30  d   1
m2  66  d   1
m3  36  d   1
m1  39  d   4
m2  49  d   4
m3  39  d   4
m1  26  d   2
m2  45  d   2
m3  48  d   2
m1  33  d   3
m2  33  d   3
m3  53  d   3
```

Comment: `*` is a short-cut for `+` (main effects) and `:` (interaction). You want to specify an `Error` term. Google "r repeated measures anova".